# Personal Macro Workbook Vs Add-In

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am new to VBA and I am trying to determine when to use the Excel Personal Macro Workbook Vs Excel Add-Ins.  I am using Office 365 Subscription (up to date) on a single Win10Pro PC.

My understanding is that if one wanted to write a Sub or Function once, and yet have access to it in all open workbooks on the same machine (which is fine for my code), then one could either place the code in the Excel Personal Macro Workbook OR create an Excel Add-In.

Some [sites](https://www.theexcelfactor.com/personal-macros-personal-xlsb-or-add-in/) suggest this is simply a matter of preference.  Is that indeed the consensus or is there a general set of guidelines for deciding when to utilize one method over the other?

Comment: Go with the personal workbook until you hit its limits. Then re-consider using an add-in in the light of what you will then know. Basically, an add-in needs a little more management and would be more inclined toward doing one specific, complicated task, meaning less flexibility. On the other hand, General Purpose macros tend to end up less flexible than one first thought. The winner is the workbook with customized code in it, supported by a library to store recurring procedures for their basic structure, then move copies thereof to individual projects where they are customized so suit.

Comment: I think @Variatus answer is pretty good and I agree with every point made. I'll add that if you are inclined to spend a bit of money, I find the MZ-Tool VBE add in to be invaluable. Among many other features, it allows you to have a code library, which is the main reason i use it. With that, you can quickly drop in code you've used before. That said, this solution has the draw back that you a)need to spend money and b) need admin rights to install it on your PC.

Comment: Thank you Variatus for your experienced guidance, and thank you rohrl77 for sharing a THIRD (out of the box) option. Excel/VBA forces one to store macros within it.  Does the code library feature of MZ-Tool open this limitation up to allow importing of code files (perhaps in .txt format) from anywhere on the C: drive (of course more than that would be gravy)?

Comment: VBA doesn't force you to store procedures within it, although I do precisely that and find it convenient. When you `Export` a module it will be saved as a Text file (2 text files in case of User Forms) which you can load into VBA projects using the `Import` function.

Comment: Variatus, you just made my day!  That is exactly the kind of flexibility and accessibility I was looking for - to work either in or out of excel and import/export as needed. I can see you've earned and deserve your 10K+ reputation credits!